# How to change Sass styles from material-components-web correctly?

Tags: css, sass, material-components

I'm styling https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web to fit to the respective angular material design components https://material.angular.io/components/categories.

Since I'm new to Sass, I'm no quite sure if I'm doing that the correct way.

Example:

I'm trying to change the text input so, that it doesn't have a background when it's highlighted + no background color at all + no padding to the left.
Right now my code for this looks like this:

app.scss

```
@import "styles/theming";
$mdc-text-field-background: transparent;
@import "~material-components-web/material-components-web";
@import "styles/inputs";
```

inputs.scss

```
.mdc-text-field::before, .mdc-text-field::after {
  content: none;
}

.mdc-text-field .mdc-floating-label {
  left: 0;
}

.mdc-text-field__input {
  padding: 20px 0 6px;
}
```

The problem here is, that I need to set `$mdc-text-field-background` before importing `material-components-web`, but setting the other input styles afterwards.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: could you not add the background inside the theming file?